# php mcrypt_encrypt() not working windows server plesk

Tags: windows-server-2008, php

I get the following error on my server (windows server with plesk 11):

**Fatal error**:  Call to undefined function mcrypt_encrypt() in **processLogin.php** on line **30**

I've tried PHP 5.2 and 5.3, the .ini files both contain the dll file.

How do I get the mcrypt_encrypt() function working?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get hold of [php_mcrypt.dll](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.extensions.php) if you don't already have a copy in your PHP extensions directory and enable it in your php.ini file. You'll also need [libmrypt.dll](http://files.edin.dk/php/win32/mcrypt/) somewhere PHP can find it.